# How to GET from FTP url in meteor.js?

Tags: node.js, meteor, javascript, ftp-client

In MeteorJS, I can't figure out how to retrieve data from a URL that starts with 'ftp' instead of the usual 'http'. The URL is ftp://webftp.vancouver.ca/OpenData/json/drinking_fountains.json

In the off-chance that the standard meteor http package might emulate FTP, I wishfully attempted to use meteor's [HTTP.get(url)](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_get) call, but got the error:

```
url must be absolute and start with http:// or https://
```

I searched google and [AtmosphereJS](https://atmospherejs.com/) for a Meteor package to provide FTP client functionality, but didn't find anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a combination of [meteorhacks:npm](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm) and a package like [ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript only 'speaks' http and websockets. If you need to emulate an FTP client within the browser there are ways to do that using Java or Flash plugins. **Generally this will not be the best way to solve the problem**.

Alternatively, you can use an NPM package on the server-side of meteor, such as, [jsftp](https://github.com/sergi/jsftp) which gets the file and then serves it to the client when requested.

Comment: Thanks Mr D. This explained what was going on and how to tackle it. I was able to get it going with your guidance. For others trying to do the same, my code is at: https://github.com/Digital-Thor/FountCouver.